# Websocket support in managed vm

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I've tried using [websockets](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket) within my Golang application served from Google's [managed vm](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/managed-vms/) but I couldn't get it to work, from Chrome developer console I'm getting:

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:8080/connect' failed: Error
>   during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400" and on my
>   backend I'm getting: "websocket: connection header != upgrade.

My question, does managed vm supports Golang websockets? If so a code snip would be appreciated.

Comment: You may see that error if you are trying to access the server from the APP_ID.appspot.com url.  You should access the instance directly by public ip (or CNAME).  If running locally, since you mentioned 127.0.0.1, then use the docker container ip.

Comment: Still no luck,
I've deployed my app to "production", updated my websocket url to point to my appspot url (i'm running only one instance for the time being) and i'm still receiving: "WebSocket connection to 'ws://APPID.appspot.com/connect' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400"

Comment: You cannot use the appspot.com url for websockets.  You need to use the ip address of the managed-vm to hit the server directly.  Using the appspot.com url, you are hitting other Google frontend servers before you get to the app.

Answer (score 0):

As per Google's [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/managed-vms/sdk) and the [example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-websocketchat-java) included over there, Managed VMs supports WebSocket in "Java" language as for now. May be in the future release (as Managed VMs is still in its Beta version), "GO" language will be put into consideration for addressing such functionality and/or feature.