# WebSocket WS SSL

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, ssl, websocket, google-managed-vm

I'm using Google App Engine/Managed VMs to develop a nodeJS application using web sockets.

As part of the app, the front end needs to connect using Websockets
e.g.

```
connection = new WebSocket('wss://127.0.0.1:3001');
```

The bit that I'm struggling with is how to ensure that the SSL part works.
My current code to start the WebSocketServer is:

`var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server;`

`var wss = new WebSocketServer({port:3001});`

but this only creates a standard server (ie ws://127.0.0.1:3001).

My question is, using WebSocketServer, how do I create a WebSocketServer for use with SSL?

Comment: Yeah, sadly we just don't support websockets yet.  If you don't want to stand up your own VM as described below, pubnub is another nice option: https://www.pubnub.com/documentation/

Comment: I found this in search results for `node einaros https`, but the accepted answer didn't help me. In case anyone else finds this, here's a related question [How to Create Secure (TLS/SSL) Websocket Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31338927/722036) with my answer posted. Tried to eliminate the confusion, so hopefully this helps someone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using secure WebSockets requires an SSL cert, and using a self-signed cert is an option. There is a [tutorial](http://www.chovy.com/web-development/self-signed-certs-with-secure-websockets-in-node-js/) which may be useful for getting this set up.

Using WebSockets on Managed VMs may present other problems though due to port forwarding issues from the appspot.com frontend. There is a [public issue](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11570) which details this as well as another [question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27827752/websocket-support-in-managed-vm). You may need to use full Compute Engine instances instead of Managed VMs as a workaround.

Comment: Cheers for the reply.
I've searched high and low but can't find any examples on how to run Secure Websockets on GCE but keep running into issues.

I keep getting the error Bad Request 400.
Do I have to refer to the websocket by ip, or can I refer to it by site/domain?

Comment: You can refer to sockets by IP or by domain as long as you have a static IP set up for the instance and the relevant domain mapping set up. You may want to consider opening a new question for issues with WebSockets on GCE regarding the 400.