# Cannot connect to wss with Flutter

Tags: android, ssl, flutter, websocket, openssl

I wrote a wss server in Nodejs and now I'm trying to connect to such server using Flutter.

**Here's the code in NodeJS:**

```
//Dependencies
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const fs = require('fs');
const https = require('https');
//Dependencies

//Server declarations
const server = https.createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync('pathTo/key.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('pathTo/cert.pem')
});
server.listen(xxxx);
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ server });
//Server declarations

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws)
{
  ws.on('message', function incoming(message)
  {
      console.log('Received: ' + message);
      ws.send('echo: ' + message);
   });
   ws.send('Connected!');
});
```

**Here's the code in Flutter:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:web_socket_channel/io.dart';
import 'package:connectivity/connectivity.dart';
import 'package:web_socket_channel/web_socket_channel.dart';

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget
{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)
  {
    final title = 'LumenApp Prototype';
    IOWebSocketChannel channel;
    try
    {
      channel = new IOWebSocketChannel.connect('wss://xxxxxxxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx/');
      MyHomePageState.noResponse = false;
    }
    catch(e)
    {
      MyHomePageState.noResponse = true;
    }
    return MaterialApp(
      title: title,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        primaryTextTheme: TextTheme(
          title: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.yellow[600],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(
        title: title,
        channel: channel,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The error on Flutter is: *WebSocketChannelException: WebSocketChannelException: HandshakeException: Handshake error in client (OS Error: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: self signed certificate(handshake.cc:354))*

This happens inside this function:

```
  void initPlatformState()
  {
    widget.channel.stream.listen((message)
    {
      setState(() { noResponse = false; });
      //Handle message...
    },
    onError: (error)
    {
      print(error);
      if(mounted)
      {
        setState((){ noResponse = true;});
      }
    },
    onDone: ()
    {
      if(mounted)
      {
        setState((){ noResponse = true; });
      }
    });
  }
```

I used a self-signed certificate server-side made with openssl.
Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: The first assumption would be that your websocket server doesn't have an SSL certificate, and as such cannot run WSS.

Comment: @JoãoSoares I got an ssl key and an ssl certificate using OpenSSL.

Comment: Have you tested that your WSS is working properly on a different client that isn't your Flutter app?

Comment: @JoãoSoares I tried with Postman, but it doesn't work either way, neither with ws nor with wss, even when with ws and Flutter it works.

Comment: There's definitely something odd going on there, but you need to make sure your server is working properly before moving on to seeing if there's a problem on your Flutter app.

Comment: @JoãoSoares okay, I tried with the web socket testing google chrome extension and it works just fine with ws. With wss it tries to open the channel for a little while and then it prompts "error". I guess the problem is on server side, but I can't tell what it is.

Comment: My knowledge of NodeJS WebSockets is limited, but strangely I can't find the SSL settings for the [`ws`](https://github.com/websockets/ws/blob/HEAD/doc/ws.md#class-websocketserver) NodeJS package for WebSockets. Maybe this might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35190045/websocket-ws-ssl

Comment: @JoãoSoares I edited the post with new information.

Comment: Can you please share your Flutter code and which package you are using as a WebSocket client?

Comment: @JoãoSoares sure, done.

Comment: It doesn't seem like there's any issue on the Flutter side. I wish I could help you more on the NodeJS side, but it's just outside my area of knowledge. I can only suggest trying to connect to a public WebSocket API with your Flutter App to test if it is working correctly.

Comment: @JoãoSoares yes it does. Btw I found the error, so I'll edit my question with it.

Comment: That's great. I'm sorry I couldn't help you more.

Comment: @JoãoSoares do not worry, I found the error because of your comments.

Comment: I'm glad. Good luck with your app!

Comment: @JoãoSoares thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you happen to bumped in [this GitHub post](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19588#), you can follow the temporary fix from [this comment](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19588#issuecomment-406779390):

> ```
> class MyHttpOverrides extends HttpOverrides{
>   @override
>   HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext context){
>     return super.createHttpClient(context)
>       ..badCertificateCallback = (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port)=> true;
>   }
> }
>
> void main(){
>     HttpOverrides.global = new MyHttpOverrides();
>     runApp(new MyApp());
> }
> ```

It works on local ip with self signed certificate.

To elaborate, [here is the same solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61312927):

> Just for the sake of clarity specially for the newcomers to
> Flutter/Dart, here is what you need to do in order to enable this
> option globally in your project:
>
> 1. In your main.dart file, add or import the following class:
>
> > ````
> > HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext? context){
> >     return super.createHttpClient(context)
> >       ..badCertificateCallback = (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port)=> true;   } } ```
> > ````
>
> 2. In your main function, add the following line after function definition:
>
> > HttpOverrides.global = MyHttpOverrides();
>
> [This](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19588#issuecomment-406779390)
> comment was very helpful to pass through this matter, and **please
> note that...**
>
> > **This should be used while in development mode, do NOT do this when
> > you want to release to production, the aim of this answer is to make
> > the development a bit easier for you, for production, you need to fix
> > your certificate issue and use it properly, look at the other answers
> > for this as it might be helpful for your case.**

Another thing worth mentioning, signed certificates are available for free now (https://letsencrypt.org/).

Also, I think the Flutter team is working to [enhance the documentation](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19588#issuecomment-406795449) for better reference regarding this issue. It is being tracked [here](https://github.com/flutter/website/issues/1846).